# X11/XCB/Xlib: Copy root window to pixmap

Tags: linux, x11, xlib, xserver, xcb

I can copy the contents of the root window to an `xcb_image_t` in client (ie. CPU) memory using `xcb_image_get()` (regardless of its *map* status, although presumably the root window is always *mapped*?). Eg:

```
xcb_image_t* xcb_img = xcb_image_get(xcb_connection, xcb_screen->root, 0, 0, xcb_screen->width_in_pixels, xcb_screen->height_in_pixels, 0x00ffffff, XCB_IMAGE_FORMAT_Z_PIXMAP);
```

Now the pixels of the root window are in `xcb_img->data`.

But I'm trying to copy the contents of the root window to an `xcb_pixmap_t` (in server memory), and it's not working (the call doesn't 
 fail, but it returns garbage, as if the window wasn't mapped):

```
  xcb_void_cookie_t    copy_cookie = xcb_copy_area_checked(xcb_connection, xcb_screen->root, xcb_pixmap, xcb_gc_null, 0, 0, 0, 0, xcb_screen->width_in_pixels, xcb_screen->height_in_pixels);
  xcb_generic_error_t* copy_error  = xcb_request_check(xcb_connection, copy_cookie);
  if(copy_error)
    exit(1);
```

However, it works for other windows that happen to be mapped (and it fails for subregions of those windows that are occluded by other windows, in the sense that the copy returns garbage.)

I understand that a window needs to be *mapped* in order to have meaninful contents. This leads me to think that the root window is *never* mapped (or something).

> All I want is to copy the contents of the display (ie. the pixels that are currently being shown in the *physical* display/monitor) to an `xcb_pixmap_t` (or, equivalently, to an Xlib `Pixmap`). How can I do this? (It works so easily for `xcb_get_image()`...)

Comment: How is your xcb_gc_null created? What is its subwindow mode? Does it work if you set that to IncludeInferiors, i.e. XCB_GC_SUBWINDOW_MODE to XCB_SUBWINDOW_MODE_INCLUDE_INFERIORS (either in `xcb_create_gc` or later with `xcb_change_gc`)

Comment: Hi Uli! Your idea *worked*! Thanks a lot for giving attention to this outside of the xcb mailing list =) I thought I couldn't access the root window's pixels because the window manager already owned it! (I think the first client to claim "ownership" over the root window gets full control, and other clients get *access error*, or something). I wonder why `XCB_SUBWINDOW_MODE_INCLUDE_INFERIORS` made all the difference? `xcb_gc_null` is just (what I think of as) the "trivial" gc, ie. `xcb_create_gc(connection, xcb_gc_null, window_xid, XCB_GC_GRAPHICS_EXPOSURES, (u32[]){XCB_EXPOSURES_NOT_ALLOWED})`

Comment: The only ownership that the WM has is selecting SubstructureRedirect on the root window. Only one client can do that at the same time. This has nothing to do with drawing, but is only involved in the creation and mapping of new windows.  See my answer for a description of SubwindowMode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want your GC to have SubwindowMode set to IncludeInferiors (default is ClipByChildren).

From the X11 protocol description:

> For ClipByChildren, both source and destination windows are additionally clipped by all viewable InputOutput children. For IncludeInferiors, neither source nor destination window is clipped by inferiors. This will result in including subwindow contents in the source and drawing through subwindow boundaries of the destination. The use of IncludeInferiors with a source or destination window of one depth with mapped inferiors of differing depth is not illegal, but the semantics is undefined by the core protocol.

https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.5/doc/x11proto/proto.html

What this means is that with ClipByChildren, you are only copying from the window that you used as the source. If the window has subwindows, the pixels "in there" are not owned by the window you are using as the source. Thus, X11 assumes you do not want those pixels.

Comment: Thanks so much! What does `drawing through subwindow boundaries` mean?

Comment: Imagine that you xcb_copy_area *to* the root window. With ClipByChildren, only the part where the root window is actually visible is drawn to (think: only draws to your wallpaper). With IncludeInferios, this will instead draw over all windows.